# Group data by weeks since the start of event in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m a data analyst in the insurance industry and we currently have a program in SAS EG that tracks catastrophe development week by week since the start of the event for all of the catastrophic events that are reported.

(I.E week 1 is catastrophe start date + 7 days, week 2 would be end of week 1 + 7 days and so on) then all transaction amounts (dollars) for the specific catastrophes would be grouped into the respective weeks based on the date each transaction was made.

Problem that we’re faced with is we are moving away from SAS EG to GCP big query and the current process of calculating those weeks is a manually read in list which isn’t very efficient and not easily translated to BigQuery.

Curious if anybody has an idea that would allow me to calculate each week number in periods of 7 days since the start of an event in SQL or has an idea specific for BigQuery? There would be different start dates for each event.

It is complex, I know and I’m willing to give more explanation as needed. Open to any ideas for this as I haven’t been able to find anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show some input data and what output you want from it.  Show what you tried.  How did it not meet your needs?